# XLOOKUP searching with last characters of string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to use XLOOKUP to search a column of long product barcode strings 'e.g 8127301822381' and return its the position in the database 'e.g position 125, 150, 550, etc'.

Is there a way for XLOOKUP's `lookup_value` to ignore all of the characters of the strings in the column except for the last 5 characters?

I ask this because barcodes are different in our suppliers and our database, except for the final few numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `lookup_value` in the `RIGHT` function, like this:

```
RIGHT(lookup_value,5)
```

Suppose your data are in A2:A1000, then your formula begins like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2:A1000,5),...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lookup data (barcodes) are in A1:A1000, and your lookup value is in B1, and you want the position of the result of the lookup, not the value there, then `MATCH()` or XMATCH()` is actually the best way to get it as it finds that position directly, no lookup step, then locating step.

I understand `XLOOKUP()` can be made to give a cell reference, but you still have to convert that to a position. Even if that is an easy step given your exact conditions, it is still a step.

As to examining only the last five characters of the barcodes, you put them (not the lookup value!) in the `RIGHT(A1:A1000,5)` function. So, putting it all together, it looks like:

```
=MATCH(B1,RIGHT(A1:A1000,5),0)
```

And that's the exact position in the database.

Comment: As @Jeorje said - you can use XLOOKUP to return the cell.  Either wrap it in `ROW()` to return the row number, or with the help of `LET` you could do something like `=LET(Return,XLOOKUP(D4,$K$2:$K$7,$L$2:$L$7),Row,ROW(Return),Col,COLUMN(Return),ADDRESS(Row,Col))` to return the full address.